# displaytag pagination javascript counting checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, paging, displaytag

I have a displaytag table which uses the checkbox decorator to keep track of selected values in the table. I'm trying to use Jquery to keep track of the # of selected values in the table for validation purposes.

What would be the best way to count the # of selected values in the table when paging through the table?

**Solution**

I added a listener to each checkbox so that it completes a count when the value changes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {          
$('.ids').find("input:checkbox").each(function() {
    $(this).click( function() {
        count = recount();
            });
    });
});

function recount() {
    var c = 0;
    var hiddenCount = $('input[type=hidden][name=_chk]');
    if (hiddenCount != null) 
        c = hiddenCount.length;
    var visibleCount = $("[type='checkbox']:checked[name=_chk]");
    if (visibleCount != null) 
        c += visibleCount.length;
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can select all the items for example

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked")
```

and count them:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length
```

Comment: how would i do this when the user selects a new page? is there a paging event I have to listen to?

Comment: you can use different selectors for every page for example, or try using .is(":visible")

Comment: will this be able to keep the count across all pages?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It helped me solve my problem. :) Will post solution in my post.

Comment: are you using jquery datatables?

Comment: I am getting data through a request with the displaytable library.

Comment: your post above helped quite a lot. :) I don't plan to introduce new libraries though, since the rest of the application currently uses display tables for less complicated functions, and what I have functioning now will suffice. the main feature im trying to add would be nice to have but not required - updating # of selected checkboxes with each page change.